# Existence and Asymptotic behavior of nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

Let $u = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$ be a divergence free vector, $P$ a skew symmetric 3 by 3 matrix with determinant zero, $dx = (dx_1,dx_2,dx_3)$ and $g$ a scalar field. Consider the reaction diffusion equation:

$[ u_t - \Delta_x u -Pu + \nabla_x(||u||^2)].dx = \nabla_x g.dx,$

$u(x,0)= u_0(x).$

I want to study the existence and asymptotic behavior of the solution.

I wanted trying the energy method but i don't know how to define the energy function in this case. Any suggestions to this or other approach will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: One strategy is to multiply the equation by some weight, integrate both sides, integrate by parts, and hope some terms go away. For example if you take the dot product of both sides with $u$, the nonlinear term and the right hand side vanish since $u$ is divergence-free. Then you have $\frac12 \partial_t \int |u|^2 + |\nabla u|^2 \ dx = \int u \cdot Pu \ dx = 0$.

Comment: Apologies, the $\partial_t$ should only be applied to $|u|^2$. In particular this implies the $L^2$ norm is decreasing.